# how to run ng-repeat by hardcoding value instead of passing array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, typescript

I want manually run the `ng-repeat` by hardcode number. I don't want to pass `array` parameter. I have tried below code but It's does not work!

```
<h1 ng-repeat="x in 20">{{sumofTwendy(($index}})</h1>
```

---

> So I have planed to create a dummy array in `controller` and assign value `20` to length of that array. then I pass the array on `ng-repeat.

```
   $scope.data=[];
   $scope.data.length=20;
   <h1 ng-repeat="x in data">{{sumofTwendy(($index}})</h1>
```

this is also does not working :( .

---

> How can we run  `ng-repeat` only by 20 times without passing array values?

*let me know the solution if it angular 1 or angular 2?*

Comment: why I need to call a function in every method? Why you marked as duplicate it?

Comment: Second one is also not suitable to my answer. actually read my question clearly.

Answer (score 0):

Just create array with length 20:

```
new Array(20);
```

Comment: but new Array() is not an best practice

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do by passing variable to a function and generate a new array,

```js
var myApp=angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('thecontroller',function($scope){
$scope.getNumber = function(num) {
    return new Array(num);   
}
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>ng-Messages Service</title>
        <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
        <script src='https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.0-rc.0/angular.min.js'></script>     
    </head>
    <body ng-app="myApp">

        <div ng-controller='thecontroller'>
    <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="i in getNumber(20) track by $index"><span>{{$index+1}}</span></li>
</ul>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```